# Does adding same library dependency to different Android gradle modules increase APK size?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

If I have multiple modules in my android project and I add a library dependency (like dagger or appcompat) in (say) 2 of those modules, will that library add twice of its size to the final APK size or will there be just one copy of the library in the final APK?

Also what if I use different versions of the library in different modules, how much will the APK size increase?

Comment: I think you should analyze debug apk to check the size

Comment: Only one copy…………

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks. And for the second part of the question, will both versions have one full copy of the library?

Comment: Here's how Gradle handles resolving which version of a dependency the project will use: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html Whether the "full" library is included depends on whether you're using code-shrinking to remove unused methods, classes etc: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: @cactustictacs So if I use the same library versions in all modules, there won't be any additional memory usage, just one copy will be there. Is that correct?

Comment: @ArpitShukla "Gradle will consider all requested versions, wherever they appear in the dependency graph. Out of these versions, it will select the *highest* one."

Comment: In that case, what will happen if I am using some function of the library which has been removed in its newer version and the newer version is being used in some other module? Will the first module break as the function is no longer available in the newer version?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same question which you asked so I tested this scenario and create a project with more then one module and place the pdf dependency
**implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'**
in different module and then build the apk but **there is no change in size of apk** either to put dependency in one module or more then one module.

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: When you use different version of PdfViewer Library to different Modules, then what happened?